# React + Express CORS error 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I am trying to make asynchronous requests from a React app to an Express backend. But I am getting the usual "CORS issue: Bad request":

[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WxaL.png)

I am aware of CORS plugin for Express so I have installed `cors` from Node Plugin Manager and applied to my backend `index.js` like:

```
...
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
...

const app = express();
...

const whitelist = [
  'http://localhost:3000'
]
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
...

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('server running on port 4000);
```

So I have tried with Fecth API to retrieve data from the backend server:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { componentId } = this.props.match.params;

    (async () => {
      const query = `
        query {
          getComponent(id: "${componentId}") {
            type
          }
        }
      `;

      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(query)
      };

      const component = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', options);

      console.log(component);
    })();

    return (
      <h1>Hola</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default Component;
```

I have tried also setting `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json }`, `mode: cors` and `crossOrigin` to `true`.

I get the same error everytime with any configuration. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Are you using chrome? Then maybe your problem is, that Chrome does not support cors from localhost ( https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743 ). Tried with any other browser ?

Comment: I have tried also in Firefox but error response is 500, regarding again to "cors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dev environment you can add the proxy in the package.json file:
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"

Your package.json should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
```

As already said, Chrome doesn't allow to make request when you are using localhost domain. Using a proxy, everything that isn't an image, css, js, etc, will consider the proxy. So when you will make the request just use fetch('/graphql'), **without the domain**.

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: okay ... it is kinda working, I have another issue but this one was solved... Thank you.