# gatsbyjs and expressjs Error 400 Bad Request while fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, gatsby

I have a small backend with ExpressJS that sends an email, **I have deployed this backend on a Heroku site**, I have tried it with postman and everything is ok, it works, but when I want to use it from my gatsby site, it throws a problem with cors, **the gatsby site is running on my localhost.**

ExpressJS code:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import cors from 'cors';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  dotenv.config();
}

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const contactAddress = process.env.CONTACT_ADDRESS || '';

const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.GMAIL_ADDRESS,
    pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASSWORD,
  },
});

app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.from)
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'From is required' });
  if (!req.body.message)
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Message is required' });
  mailer.sendMail(
    {
      from: req.body.from,
      to: [contactAddress],
      subject: 'Contact from API',
      html: `<h3>${req.body.from}</h3><br>${req.body.message}`,
    },
    (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }
      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    }
  );
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
console.log(`App running on port ${process.env.PORT || 8000}`);
```

Code on frontend that make the request:

```
const onSubmit = async (data: IFormInputs) => {
    console.log(data);
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(data).forEach((el) => {
      formData.append(el, data[el]);
    });

    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}contact`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });

      console.log(res);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

I have also tried adding some configuration on the fetch, but it does not work anyways

```
const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}contact`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
          },
          referrerPolicy: 'origin', 
            body: formData,
          });
```

The error throws the following error:

```
{
 status: 400,
 statusText: "Bad Request",
 type: "cors",
 ok: false,
}
```

I have searched similar questions on StackOverflow, but any of the solutions have worked for me.

The answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853080/react-express-cors-error-400-bad-request) does not work for me, because I don't have the backend and the frontend on localhost, I am consuming the API from my Heroku site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React + Express CORS error 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853080/react-express-cors-error-400-bad-request)

Comment: @Taki No, I have tried that solution too, I think that question has both frontend and backend on localhost, and that's because they use the proxy on the package.json, meanwhile my backend is hosted on a heroku site, I have already added the `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"` on my package.json frontend, and I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are listening on the port `8000`. Are you sure it's correct? Let's try on posts `8080`.
2. You can also set headers:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

Comment: The backend listens on the port listed on the env variables on Heroku, when I fetch with postman I only write the hostname and the action '/contact', I don't write any port, so I don't think it is necessary. And I think that the cors() middleware is setting all of those configurations up, do I need to do all the setup again?